# TypeError: Failed to excute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Reponse': body stream already read in Dotnet6 Blazor wasm with using the iframe for tablet

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

We use the dotnet6 blazor wasm pwa for two projects.
We use the iframe in the first  blazor wasm project.
We call the second project from it with using the iframe.

There has no error computer browser and mobile browser.

**There has the error in tablet browser only.**

**"TypeError: Failed to excute 'arrayBuffer'  on 'Reponse': body stream already read in Dotnet6 Blazor wasm"
or
"TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Argument 0 must be a buffer source or a WebAssembly.Module object"**

```js
  return s.instantiateWasm = (e,t)=>((async()=>{
        let n;
        try {
            const t = await u;
            n = await async function(e, t) {
            if ("function" == typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming) {
                
                try {
                    return (await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(e.response, t)).instance
                } catch (e) {
                    console.info("Streaming compilation failed. Falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation. ", e)
                }
            }
            
        const n = await e.response.then((e=> {
             e.arrayBuffer(); // This is error because of e.reponse is empty.
        }));
        

        return (await WebAssembly.instantiate(n, t)).instance // this is error because argument 0 must be a buffer source or a WebAssembly.Module object
           }(t, e)
        } catch (e) {
            throw s.printErr(e.toString()),
            e
        }
        t(n)
```

Comment: Try to format your code properly (use [edit]).

Comment: Do you have a middleware that reads the response. İf yes you should enable response buffering

Comment: This error will appear in blazor.webassembly.js Thank you

Comment: @ThantZinTun Did you ever solve this issue? I'm getting a similar exception in Chrome for Android and Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 0):

This needs a fix, at the moment I'd actively discourage anyone that's developing for mobile users to avoid using Blazor WASM until it's fixed!

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61925